# help with a PHP regex to extract text around a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to use a regular expression and it's just breaking my brain.  I'll think I have it and the the script just breaks. I need to try to give people a way to report their location via SMS. I ask them to text me a string that looks like this:

> I give up, stopping for the night.
>   Find me at Main Street and Pine,
>   Atlanta, GA.

And I want to break it at `Find me at`. I need to capture everything to the right of that (*essentially their street corner*) and I need to be able to detect if they didn't use proper capitalization for `Find`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question, but I find this site useful: [http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/). Download the PDF and keep it handy.

Comment: @Tieson Good resource, though their email regex is horrendous.

Comment: @Crashspeeder No doubt. I think Dave even admits as much somewhere on the site. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_match("/[Ff]ind me at (.+)/", "I give up, find me at street 1 and street 2")` will capture everything after the "find me at"

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will work for you:

`Find me at (.*)$`

If you want it to ignore the case, you can specify it using the *IgnoreCase* option `(?i:)`

Comment: @Crashspeeder You're correct. For some reason I thought that was the begining of the text :)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot: `/find me at (.*)$/i`

Comment: It looks like this one would work, but I saw the last entry first. Would this regex also catch a different case with find/Find?

Comment: @mcleodm3 Yes, that's what the `i` after the delimiter means.  The whole regular expression is case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a non-regexp solution comes to mind.

```
$string = 'I give up, stopping for the night. Find me at Main Street and Pine, Atlanta, GA.';
$findMe = 'Find me at';
$address = substr(strstr($string, $findMe), strlen($findMe));
if ($address == '') {
    // no match
}
```

Then there is a regexp-based solution.

```
preg_match('/Find me at (.*)$/', $string, $match);
if (!isset($match[1])) {
    // no match found
} else {
    $address = $match[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just preg_split(). If you know what you want should always be at the end.

```
$str = "I give up, stopping for the night. Find me at Main Street and Pine, Atlanta, GA."

$strSplit = preg_split("/Find me at /i", $str);

$whatYouWant = $strSplit[1];
```